# Sci-fi book with a female main character who can teleport and goes on one or more missions

Tags: story-identification, books, teleportation

Around 10 years ago, I checked out an old sci-fi book from the library, however I regret not finishing it. I’m not much of a reader, but it’s the only book I stopped reading mid-way through. I hope to find its name so I can finish it. The details, as I recall them (my memory isn’t great), are below. Thank you for your help.

- Sci-fi book with a female main character (FMC)
- Her powers: she could teleport (I think she could also drift or hide in planes or dimensions - as a catalyst for transport and/or to conceal herself from danger). I also remember this activity was dangerous for her, as there were risks, i.e. possible death or being lost in-between worlds indefinitely
- Possibly a mercenary or spy? I recall her receiving electronic payment for a mission or missions, however I don’t recall her actually killing anyone
- I don’t recall much of the world or worlds unfortunately, but I think it was possibly a futuristic dystopia
- I assumed the book was older at the the time of reading, as the cover appeared to be an early 90’s or even older - (80’s or older?), as the cover was drawn with a common 80’s art style, however that’s just my speculation
- I vaguely recall the FMC on the cover, but can’t remember any details

Thank you, and my apologies for the lack of details. I know my question is a shot in the dark, but figured I should at least try.

Comment: I'm uncertain on my answer, but if anyone does post the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps *[The Cat Who Walks Through Walls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat_Who_Walks_Through_Walls)* by Robert A. Heinlein?

[image: Front cover of The Cat Who Walks Through Walls]

> A writer seated at the best restaurant of the space habitat "Golden Rule" is approached by a man who urges him that "Tolliver must die" and is himself shot before the writer's eyes. The writer—Colonel Colin Campbell, living under a number of aliases including his pen name "Richard Ames"—is joined by a beautiful and sophisticated lady, Gwendolyn Novak, who helps him flee to Luna with a bonsai maple and a would-be murderer ("Bill"). After escaping to the Moon, Gwen claims to have been present during the revolt described in The Moon Is a Harsh Mistress.
>
> Still pursued by assassins, Campbell and Novak are rescued by an organization known as the Time Corps under the leadership of Lazarus Long. After giving Campbell a new foot to replace one lost in combat years before, the Time Corps attempts to recruit Campbell for a special mission. Accepting only on Gwen's account, Campbell agrees to assist a team to retrieve the decommissioned Mike, a sentient computer introduced in The Moon Is a Harsh Mistress. Engaged in frequent time-travel, the Time Corps has been responsible for changing various events in the past, creating an alternate universe with every time-line they disrupt. Mike's assistance is needed in order to accurately predict the conditions and following events in each of the new universes created. Campbell's frequent would-be assassins are revealed to be members of contemporary agencies also engaged in time manipulation who, for unknown reasons, do not want to see Mike rescued by the Time Corps.

Gwen, as a Time Agent, has the ability to move back and forth in time. The eponymous cat is actually a cat, who is able to walk through walls because they don't know they can't. It was published in 1985, and the cover art does feature the female lead in what might be considered a very 80s style.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I don’t think that’s the book, however it does sound very entertaining; I think I’ll have to check it out. Based on my memory, I think the main character worked alone (at least as far as I read).

Comment: @jim *The Cat Who Walks Through Walls* is likely to be entertaining if you're a big Heinlein fan—since in the second half of the book, Heinlein indulges in a ton of interdimensional continuity porn, crossing over with a bunch of his other works.  If you're not that kind of fan, however, it can be a *huge* letdown.

Answer (score 0):

Could it possibly be part of Zelazny's [Chronicles of Amber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Amber)?

It also sounds similar to Stross' [Merchant Princes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Merchant_Princes), but the release date doesn't fit into an 80s/early 90s release

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  First, you should only post one answer at a time; putting two different answers in the same post makes it hard to mark one of them as correct.  Secondly, you should explore in at least a bit of detail how your answer matches the details of the question.  Would either of these be described as a futuristic dystopia?  Were there any scenes where a female spy received payment electronically?

Comment: Definitely not Amber. The main characters (Corwin and Merlin) are all male. And nothing in the Amber series comes even close to the rest of the question.